# Closest Date in PHP

Tags: php, date

Our billing cycle is 1st and 16th of every month. We want to show our users the next payout date. Ho to proceed it with PHP ?

For e.g.: Today is 7th Feb...so 16th Feb should be given as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to take care cases like 17 Dec since we need to return 1 Jan. The following code fragment calculates the next payment date:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
list($day, $month, $year) = array_map('intval', explode(',', date('j,m,Y')));
if ($day < 16)
    $day = 16;
else {
    $day = 1;
    $month = $month % 12 + 1;
    if ($month == 1) $year += 1;
}
echo date(DATE_RFC2822, mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
```

It's output for the current date:

```
Mon, 16 Feb 2015 00:00:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function get_payout_date($today, $payout_dates) {
    foreach ($payout_dates as $d) {
        if ($d > $today) return $d;
    }

    return $payout_dates[0];
}

$payout_dates = array(1, 16);
echo get_payout_date(intval(date('d')), $payout_dates);
```

And if you want to allow the same date, you can use `$d >= $today`.

You want to get full date from the payout date then:

```
$payout_date = get_payout_date(intval(date('d')), $payout_dates);
$date = date('jS M, Y', strtotime(date('Y-m-') . $payout_date));
echo $date;
```

Output: 16th Feb, 2015

Comment: Your code has a very high complexity for such a simple problem.

Comment: Yes your answer is good for this case, but what if tomorrow my payout dates are 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 24?

Comment: Yeh that is true. Your code is more flexible. But you know I answer about question. I vote up your solution.

Comment: I dont want number..1 or 16.. I want the full date with month and year..to avoid calculations to check month/year change.

Comment: @Ananth your code breaks if date is 17th i.e. the following:
      `$today = time();
 $twoMonthsLater = strtotime("+10 days", $today);
 $modified = date('d', $twoMonthsLater);
        $payout_date = get_payout_date(intval($modified), $payout_dates);`

Answer (score 2):

Just simply if:

```
$currentDay = date('j');

if ($currentDay >= 1 && $currentDay <= 16) {
    echo '16th';
} else {
    echo '1st';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hei how did you cycle your payment? mothly?
you can use

```
$next30day=date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days"));
```

$next30day should have next 30 day of current date